# Angular project don't run with ng serve?

Tags: angular

I have a angular template but it don't run with "ng serve" command.
My angular-cli.json code here:

[image]

Comment: What did you try, and what is the errors you are getting.

Comment: Just try to run the application from the project location using cmd.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also don't upload code as image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing need you check your angular version using below command if not installed then install angular cli using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --  for install angular.

ng --version - check installed angular version.
```

You can check your package.json files. below code are same or not

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "config": "ts-node set-env.ts",
    "start": "npm run config -- --environment=local && ng serve",
    "build:dev": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng build --configuration=dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build --configuration production --verbose=true",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```